# Java Check if socket sends

Tags: java, sockets

I am creating a simple Java program where the client sends a message to the server and the server replies back with a confirmation message. But my question is: Can I get the server response/broadcast before the `BufferedReader` line?

Server:

```java
public class Multithread extends Thread{
    Socket sock;
    static ArrayList<Multithread> clientList = new ArrayList<Multithread>();
    public Multithread(Socket sock){
        this.sock = sock;
    }
    public void run(){
        try{

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(this.sock.getInputStream());
            String read = in.readUTF();
            if(read.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
                System.out.println(this.sock.getRemoteSocketAddress()+" just dced");
                clientList.remove(this);
                this.sock.close();
            }
            else{
            String said = this.sock.getRemoteSocketAddress() +" said "+read;
            System.out.println(said);
            for(Multithread multi : clientList){
                DataOutputStream o = new DataOutputStream(multi.sock.getOutputStream());
                o.writeUTF(said);
            }
            this.sock.close();}
        }catch(IOException e){

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7777);
        System.out.println("Listening");
        while(true){
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected to "+socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            Multithread multi = new Multithread(socket);
            clientList.add(multi);
            multi.start();

        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```java
public class Clients{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        while(true){
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",7777);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line = br.readLine();
            out.writeUTF(line);
            if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
            {
                System.out.println("Disconnected");
                socket.close();
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Server said :"+in.readUTF());
                socket.close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the server only sends a message to the client when the client requests something it I dont see how the server could ever send a message before the client. Can you add code or elaborate on your question?

Comment: Need more code... is it UDP or TCP?

Comment: your code with more elaboration

Comment: `System.out.println("Server said :"+in.readUTF());` . Dont you think this line says it all?

Comment: What do you mean ?  i want to check in clients, before the bufferedreader line if server has sent any message.

Comment: According to **Is there anyway i can check in the client if the server did send that broadcast ?** question... my previous commment is the answer .. the else part in your Client clearly works if you want to hear the btoadcast

Comment: Do you want to hear the broadcast before the BufferredReader?

Comment: Yes, thats what i want

Comment: So .. .do you know the answer ?